# Why does git pull --rebase and git rebase give me different histories?

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase, git-pull

My git history is as follows:

```
- A - B - C   <-- origin/master
   \
    X - Y - Z    <-- origin/my-branch, my-branch (local)
```

I have two scenarios:

1. I run this on my-branch (local):

   ```
   $ git pull --rebase origin master
   ```
2. I run the following starting from my-branch on local:

   ```
   $ git checkout master
   $ git pull
   $ git checkout my-branch
   $ git rebase master
   ```

After scenario 1, my history (with `git log`) shows:

```
... - X - Y - Z - A - B - C    <-- my-branch
```

And after scenario 2, my history shows:

```
... - A - B - C - X - Y - Z    <-- my-branch
```

I want to know why is there a difference? Isn't the two set of commands supposed to do the exact same thing?

Comment: It would have given the same history if you had run the 1. on master, not on the my-branch.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the reuslts you report.  When I do `git pull --rebase origin master` I get the master commits as they exist, with my local branch rewritten after the last commit - same as your 2nd scenario output, and same as the documentation indicates.  I suspect there's an error in your observations, but if you believe they're accurate, please rerun the test and post a cut-and-paste log of the exact commands and output.